How to treat the new .NET 8 BCL deprecation warnings not as errors?
In our C# projects, we generally use the following setting:
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
<WarningsNotAsErrors>612,618</WarningsNotAsErrors>

So far, this has worked flawlessly, with the following, desired outcome:

In general, warnings are treated as errors. Thus, developers are compelled to fix them right away.
The "obsolete"/"deprecated" warnings CS0612 and CS0618 are a special case - their entire purpose is to warn before code will break in a later version, thereby creating a phase during which developers are made aware of a problem without breaking the build. Therefore, these two warnings are treated as warnings, not as errors.

With .NET 8, it seems the BCL has introduced a whole set of new warnings that certain types or members are going to be deprecated, for instance:

SYSLIB0051 - about legacy serialization support APIs
SYSLIB0050 - about formatter-based serialization
SYSLIB0040 - about certain encryption policies
SYSLIB0011 - about binary formatter serialization
and so on

In our codebase (with several hundred C# projects), we have many occurrences of these. We will fix them, but cannot do so everywhere at once.
What is an efficient way to treat these new deprecation warnings as warnings rather than as errors, without moving away from the warnings-as-errors setting in general?
(As a bit of background info, I would be interested in any insights on why it was decided to declare lots of new warnings for the .NET 8 framework deprecations rather than using the existing CS0612 and CS0618 in the first place. Maybe knowing about this helps with the decision on how to deal with this issue.)

You can do the same as what you did previously, but you should use the full names of the warnings instead. So change your setting to something like this:
<WarningsNotAsErrors>CS0612;CS0618;SYSLIB0051</WarningsNotAsErrors>

Or, to completely disable a specific warning (amending one warning to the existing exclusion list):
<NoWarn>$(NoWarn);SYSLIB0011</NoWarn>

You can also disable the warning for a particular piece of code by surrounding offending code with #pragma statements. This has the advantage that only small pieces of code are allowed to violate the rule, thus preventing that one accidentally writes new code violating a rule.
#pragma warning disable CSXXXX
// Code violating the rule
#pragma warning restore CSXXXX


OP wanted efficient way, the number of SYSLIB error means copying and pasting the numbers as and when M$ feels like adding them

@Alander Yes, of course every time a new warning is introduced, you need to take care of it (or disable it). Since you can't know what a future warning is about, it would be a bad idea to just disable all new warnings prematurely.

@PMF: "Since you can't know what a future warning is about, it would be a bad idea to just disable all new warnings prematurely." - but I'm not asking about disabling any warnings. I am asking about making sure obsoletion warnings do not break the build by getting treated as errors. And as far as I can see in the docs, all the SYSLIB#### warnings are, in fact, obsoletion warnings. As such, I agree with the above comment in that listing dozens of warning numbers, more with each .NET version, (in > 1,500 .csproj files, mind you) does not fulfil my requirement for efficiency.

You can list them in your Directory.Build.props file, so you don't need to touch 1500 files. Then it's just adding a new warning when you update the .NET version. You will have to do a bit of testing and fixing with that usually anyway. And you probably have to get rid of the previous warnings before the next version ships. E.g. you will not be able to suppress SYSLIB0011  once you upgrade to .NET 9.0, because the relevant code will be permanently gone in the runtime.
